# file_get_contents changes html tag in php

Tags: php, html

I want to load a webpage and extract some items from it. I'm using php. This is my code

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('www.website.com'); 
$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
  if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned
     echo $html;
}
?>
```

When I compare source code of www.website.com and html that I loded  I see that some tags changed. for example there is

```
<span class="str">
```

in   www.website.com sorce code which changes to

```
<h5 class="item-subtitle">
```

in my loded html. What is the reason and how can I correct it?

Comment: I doubt things change. Whats probably happening is the real page has javascript that fiddles with the page which is not running on your page. Or the page built when you use it properly rather than scrape it is built based on some server code and action that your scraper does not perform

Answer (score 0):

Some websites will change the markup with JavaScript. When you load the sites markup with `file_get_contents` you do not run its JavaScript, but actually just retrieve the HTML. Compare your retrieved HTML with "View page source" in your browser. Those should be the same.

Hopefully you can parse your stuff from that HTML, if not, you will have to contact the owner of that website and connect to their API, if they even supply one.

Comment: but retrieved HTML with "View page source" in  browser are different.

Comment: I have not forgotten about your issue, but was unavailable in the past few days. Are you sure you are looking at the page source, and not something like chrome dev tools? Navigate to `view-source:http://yourwebsite.com` and compare those two sources. Dev tools will show the JS manipulated markup, view-source will not.